# Chrome Browser refusing to connect to AWS Cloud Former instance over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, aws-cloudformation

I'm struggling to use AWS Cloud Former to generate a CloudFormation template. I have already launched the Cloud Former stack twice and attempted to connect to the associated DNS for the EC2 instance generated each time and keep receiving the error pictured below.
[image]
I have already tried to create a new SSL certification for the EC2 instance via AWS Certificate Manager, but AWS does not allow this for EC2 instances. I'm not very familiar with SSL/HTTPS processes and would appreciate any guidance on next steps I should pursue to address/troubleshoot this.

Upon further research into this, I have found the following issue:
[image]
Specifically, I'm seeing the following SSL certification issue:
[image]

Has anyone else seen this yet with CloudFormer recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFormer uses self signed certificates that are generated by the stack. This is the normal browser warning when the browser encounters a self signed certificate. For your purposes, you can simply click on the link at the bottom (`Proceed to EC2-xxx (Unsafe)`) of the warning page, and ignore the warning. You will connect successfully in spite of the warning.

Comment: I'm able to proceed, but does this mean I need to open up port 80 (HTTP) to attempt to access the CloudFormer website? Right now, when I proceed it hangs as only port 443 (HTTPS) is open in the current security group settings established by CloudFormer. Furthermore, part of the CloudFormer process is to login to the EC2 instance through the SSL certificate with username and password generated during the CloudFormer process. Does this pose an issue/barrier to accessing the website?

Comment: I'm relatively new to SO so I'm just adding this to hopefully send a notification to you. I'd like to ask a couple additional questions related to CloudFormer HTTPS. Once I did what you recommended, it ask for a certificate to authenticate myself to the instance yet I am unaware of one provided to me. All I can see from the CFN template is that username and password are used to create the SSL cert. Could you provide clarity on next steps in this process?

Comment: Apologies for the barrage of messages. I was able to login from Safari by progressing through the warning message. However, Chrome hangs once I provide the certification from my computer. Are you able to provide clarity on why this might be?

Comment: Hm no idea why chome would do that. All browsers will allow you to to accept an invalid cert in spite of the warnings. So stay on https, and continue on. It has no impact on CloudFormer operations. It's normal. Then follow the remaining steps to generate the cloud formation templates.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates require a domain. On AWS you can set one up with the certificate manager, but it will still have an issue until you correctly configure Route 53 on AWS as well.

Comment: Could you provide some context here. I'm under the working impression that AWS Certificate Manager is intended for Elastic Load Balancers, Amazon CloudFront distributions, and APIs on API Gateway as per the documentation. I'm trying to use CloudFormer which appears to have SSL certs that are not created correctly.